# Inter-project dependency causing package errors

Tags: scala, sbt

So I'm trying to split up a project into two different sub-projects to reduce compile times and I'm running into some issues.

So in my primary build.sbt looks like this:

```
lazy val Root = project.in(file("."))
  .aggregate(ProjectLib, DataQualityReport)

lazy val ProjectLib = project
.settings(Common.buildSettings: _*)
.settings(Common.assemblySettings: _*)

lazy val DataQualityReport  = project
    .settings(Common.buildSettings: _*)
    .settings(Common.assemblySettings: _*)
    .dependsOn(ProjectLib)
```

Now the issue comes when I attempt to use a test-class from the project-lib in the dataquality report. Note that `com.project.data_quality` is a package in my local project while `com.project.util` is in the ProjectLib.

```
package com.project.data_quality

import com.project.util.SparkTestSuite


class DataQualityValidatorTest extends SparkTestSuite{
```

While this code appears to be fine in intellij I get errors when I attempt to run the tests

```
HBRoot/DataQualityReport/src/test/scala/com/origami/data_quality/DataQualityValidatorTest.scala:5: 
object SparkTestSuite is not a member of package com.project.util
```

Is there something I'm not understanding between setting up the package dependencies?

Answer (score 0):

Initially I though you missed scope in dependsOn `dependsOn(ProjectLib % "test->test")` but all you did works in my setup:

https://github.com/kpbochenek/scala-playground

sub1 and sub2 reflect your subprojects, check `SparkTestReport`